# python pandas column value of the oldest date in other column

Tags: python, pandas

The data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = pd.date_range("20130101", periods=12) 
df['bol']  = np.array([0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1])
df['language'] = np.array(['FR','EN','FR','EN','FR','EN','FR','EN','FR','EN','FR','EN'])
df['doctype'] = np.array(['FAM','SELF','FAM','SELF','FAM','FAM','FAM','SELF','FAM','SELF','FAM','FAM'])
set_claims = [[i,i+1] for i in range(12)]
df['my_list'] = pd.Series(set_claims, index=df.index)
```

Now I would like to query rows with 'EN' and 'SELF'

```
df.loc[(df.language=='EN') & (df.doctype=='SELF'), ]
```

In the same line there should be a way to get only the row of the oldest item, i.e. how do I add in that line the query df['date'] being the oldest.

The ultimate goal is to get the value of my_list with language=EN, doctype = 'SELF' being the oldest.

I got a solution in two lines, but I simply dont like it. not "elegant"

```
oldest = df.loc[(df.language=='EN') & (df.doctype=='SELF'), ].date.min()
df.loc[df.date == oldest,'my_list']
```

Is there a more straight forward way to make this?

---

EDITED ANSWER:

```
myval = (df.loc[(df.language=='EN') & (df.doctype=='SELF'),]).sort_values(by='date',ascending=True).head(1)['my_list'].iloc[0]
```

If you change ascending=False then you get the most recent entry. With iloc you get the value rather than a pandas object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to `sort` your result, and use `head(1)` to get minimum date.

```
(df.loc[(df.language=='EN') & (df.doctype=='SELF'),]).sort_values(by='date').head(1)

        date  bol language doctype my_list
1 2013-01-02    1       EN    SELF  [1, 2]
```

And if you want just the `my_list` values back:

```
(df.loc[(df.language=='EN') & (df.doctype=='SELF'),]).sort_values(by='date').head(1)['my_list']

1    [1, 2]
Name: my_list, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one oldest date is possible use [`Series.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmin.html) for index of row with minimal value:

```
idx = df.loc[(df.language=='EN') & (df.doctype=='SELF'), 'date'].idxmin()
df.loc[idx,'my_list']
```